# Ventana para envío de Email en Swift 5

Tags: swift

Tengo una ViewController la cual trata de enviar un email a la empresa como parte de contacto/dudas/problemas que el usuario pueda tener.
He creado un botón el cual accede al MFMailComposerViewController, pero al pulsar sobre él salta un error *(el error que me salta es el que introduzco en el print)*. Alguna sugerencia?

Os dejo el código por aquí:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController3: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var enviarEmail: UIButton!
    

    
    
    @IBAction func enviarEmail(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    
             
        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
             if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
                self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
             } else {
                 print("Error!")
             }
         }

         func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
             let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
             mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

             mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["nurdin@gmail.com"])
             mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
             mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

             return mailComposerVC
         }

        
    
 }
```

Comment: El código funciona en el dispositivo sin el error mencionado. En qué versión de Xcode?

Comment: La versión de Xcode es la 12.0.1

Comment: En la versión 12.2 de Xcode funciona tu código. Puede ser por la versión pero podrías hacer una prueba actualizando a la última versión.